# Upload Multiple Document in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Is uploading multiple documents not enabled on Sharepoint, if I use older operating system like XP and Linux?

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things:

- Make sure you are running one of the [level 1 Web browsers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(office.12).aspx), Internet Explorer 6, 7 or 8
- Multiple file upload control requires that **Microsoft Office be installed on the client computer**. Users who have [level 2 Web browsers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(office.12).aspx) must upload documents one at a time.
- [Make sure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360) your SharePoint site is in **Trusted Sites** or **Local Intranet zone** in Internet Explorer
- If you cannot add it to one of trusted/intranet zones make sure you have no warnings about **ActiveX** controls in [Internet Explorer Warning Bar](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Internet-Explorer-Information-bar-frequently-asked-questions), run all active X controls.
- If you are uploading [multiple pictures](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/add-one-or-more-files-to-a-library-HA010092919.aspx#BM3) to a picture library, a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible image editor, such as Microsoft Office Picture Manager, may open.